# Why are my @Inject'ed fields null when using the Converter with @Param?

Tags: jsf, cdi, jboss-weld, omnifaces

I've a pretty basic setup here:

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class TalentIdConverter implements Converter {
    @EJB
    private EntityManagerDao em;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(value)) {
            return null;
        }
        return em.find(Talent.class, Long.parseLong(value));
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        return String.valueOf(((Talent) value).getId());
    }
}

// Manager.class
public class Manager {
    @Inject @Param(converterClass = TalentIdConverter.class, name = "talentId")
    private ParamValue<Talent> curTalent

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // use curTalent.getValue()
    }
}
```

But every time `TalentIdConverter.getAsObject` is called `em` is null. Can someone enlighten me why this is?
I've also tried using `@FacesConverter` on the converter, but the behavior did not change.

This is on Wildfly-8.0.0.Beta1 using Weld-2.1.0.CR1 and Omnifaces-1.6.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current 1.6.3 version, the `@Param(converterClass)` creates an **unmanaged** instance of the given converter class. It's like as if you're doing `new TalentIdConverter()` without any injection. If you need a managed instance, then you should in this specific case with a CDI-managed converter class (registered via `@Named`) be using `@Param(converter)` instead:

```
@Inject @Param(converter = "#{talentIdConverter}", name = "talentId")
private ParamValue<Talent> curTalent;
```

Or, if it's registered as a `@FacesConverter("talentIdConverter")` and thus a JSF-managed converter class (which also just [transparently](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/FacesConverter) supports EJB when you've OmniFaces 1.6 installed):

```
@Inject @Param(converter = "talentIdConverter", name = "talentId")
private ParamValue<Talent> curTalent;
```

Or, if it's registered as a `@FacesConverter(forClass=Talent.class)`, then you don't need to explicitly specify the converter anymore.

```
@Inject @Param(name = "talentId")
private ParamValue<Talent> curTalent;
```

---

On the other hand, trying to create a managed instance via `BeanManager` for `@Param(converterClass)` wouldn't have been a bad idea after all. We may look into this for future OmniFaces versions.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the `forClass` hint - that's just fine with me (although there seems to be an issue with converters inheriting from a generic base class, but that's probably PEBKAC right now)